# Tap off raw RF data from antenna

Tags: applications

I was wondering if it is possible to pull out the raw RF data from the antenna for use in an application.  I have a device that operates as a separate entity with an an antenna feed, but I am interested in trying to put our processing on an Android.  This would be the most useful if I could tap off the RF data from the existing antenna, rather than attaching a separate one.  I don't know much about Androids - just getting a feel for this before I put too much effort into the research.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the antenna on in the internals of Android handset, underneath the battery or nearby it?

If so - the short answer is no - am afraid!

The firmware and radio base-band is definitely off-limits, closed and proprietary.