# Accessing the antenna of an Android system

Tags: radio-firmware, rfid

I am asking a similar question to this
[Tap off raw RF data from antenna](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27597/tap-off-raw-rf-data-from-antenna)
but would like further explanation.

First off, I'm an electrical engineer, so I have no experience with android systems besides the average phone user experience.

What I am trying to do is use a mobile device that can read RFID data at 2.4 GHz. This is as low-level as you can get, but I know we don't have access to raw RF data. Is there a way I can collect the RFID data without needing any external peripherals?

Comment: Maybe search on [SO]? From a user perspective, I I am not sure if it can be done for the same reason in linked question

Comment: NFC in android device operates at 13.56 MHz.